# Passing arguments from one script to another, in a script

Tags: python

I am trying to pass a python script variables from another python script in a python script. What I am trying to do in code form:

file1.py

```
global x
x = 7
```

file2.py

```
print x
```

file3.py

```
import file1
import file2
```

But I always get the error x is not defined. If I import file1 in file2 and run it, it works, but if I run file2 from file3 it does not work.

Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Don't think in terms of "global variables", think in terms of explicit imports: `from file1 import x`.

Comment: `import` in Python is very different from `include` in PHP.  Each module in Python has its own namespace, and importing a module using `import foo` only adds the name `foo` to the importing moudle's namespace.

Comment: @SiHa yea you are right that would have answerde my question, I just did not find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `global`.

**file1.py**

```
x = 7
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import x

print(x)
```

**file3.py**

```
...
```

But if it was me, I'd guess you want something like this:

**file1.py**

```
def get_x(x):
    return x
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import get_x

x = get_x(3)
```

**file3.py**

```
from file2 import x

print(x)
```

As you can see, you just have to *play* around with explicit imports depending on what you need to accomplish. However, this looks weird and I can't recommend it to anyone because either one of *file1.py* or *file2.py* seem to be useless.

Here's the [doc about imports](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Yea I know, but I wrote a few scripts that depend on each other, but in case of an error I want to be able to execute each part by itself. But thanks for your help :)